# Gravitational force acting on a small element on a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity

I was given a formula that force acting on a small element on a sphere (made by connecting two hemispheres) to the center of the sphere equals:
$$dF = \frac12 \cdot G\cdot m\cdot dm/r^2$$ I cannot find out why there is this factor 1/2, if you could give me an explanation I would be grateful.

Comment: Shouldn't the factor be 2? How is $dm$ defined? Are angles involved? Doesn't $dm$ depend on $r$ and two angles? Polar coordinates are obviously used.

Comment: dm is defined as dm = m*ds/(4* PI *r^2) where ds is a small surface, I saw an explanation in case of charged sphere but the force was described as the force with which a spherical surface uniformly charged with the charge q affects the charge Q which is exactly on this surface, but this does not, in my opinion, refer to a force acting within.

Comment: Well I didn't mention but the sphere is cut in two hemispheres and those are connected and the task was to calculate the attracting force of these two hemispheres

Comment: That’s very important information and belongs in the *question*.

Comment: Is then the factor 1/2 just because of the fact that I only take into account one hemisphere?

Comment: I think so, because m becomes 1/2m in that case.

Comment: If it is the case then the equation is rather obvious but the authors of the solution made me really confused because they said that to find out from where does the coefficient 1/2 come from I can check the derivation made in electricity problem that I mentioned above and it wasn't in my opinion related anyhow to this problem.

Comment: It's still not clear whether the force you are looking for is that due to *one* hemisphere or the total of both.  You also need to make clear if this is a solid sphere or a shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you explained in a comment, “the task was to calculate the attracting force of these two hemispheres”. You are not interested in the forces between elements in the *same* hemisphere. These do not contribute to the net force between the hemispheres. You are only interested in how an element in one hemisphere is pulled by the *other* hemisphere. Hence, there is a factor of 1/2.

Comment: Yes, that is a very neat explanation that I needed to sort out my thoughts. Thank you then, because as I said earlier the authors of the solution were a bit inconsistent in the description

Comment: Do you know how it would change if instead of making it by connecting two hemispheres I would do the same with four quarters of the sphere? I think it wouldn't be 1/4 factor in front of the equation. @G. Smith